# С помощью nginx реализовать отдачу js и css с другого субдомена

Tags: nginx

Как можно реализовать отдачу скриптов и стилей, находящихся, например, на домене `example.com` c `files.example.com` на сервере nginx?

Пример конфига nginx:

```
server {
  listen         %ip%:%httpport%;
  listen         %ip%:%httpsport% ssl;
  server_name    %host% %aliases%;
  #if ($request_method !~* ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){return 403;}
  location ~ /\. {deny all;}

  location / {
    proxy_buffer_size         64k;
    proxy_buffering           on;
    proxy_buffers             4 64k;
    proxy_connect_timeout     5s;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
    proxy_intercept_errors    off;
    proxy_pass                http://%ips%:%httpbackport%/;
    proxy_pass_header         Server;
    proxy_read_timeout        5m;
    proxy_redirect            off;
    proxy_send_timeout        5m;
    proxy_set_header          Host $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js|cur|swf)$ {
    root     "%hostdir%";
    expires  7d;
  }

  location ^~ /apacheicons/ {
    alias    %sprogdir%/modules/http/%httpdriver%/icons/;
  }
  location ^~ /apacheerror/ {
    alias    %sprogdir%/modules/http/%httpdriver%/error/;
  }
}
```

Comment: А что вам мешает создать поддомен и загружать в него эти скрипты? Это даже ускорит загрузку страницы

Comment: Я таким образом изучаю настройки nginx, учусь с ним работать.

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass